# Retrieve Inputs from HTML Form as URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, get

Based off of w3schools tutorial (https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_submit), the form below will submit it's inputs in the following format: firstname=Mickey&lastname=Mouse. Is there any way to extract the inputs in this format using javascript or JQuery? Thanks!

```html
<form action="/action_page.php">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey">
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just grab it with [jQuery](https://jquery.com/):

```
$('form').serializeArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to send input fields value to URL, you have to collect all fields value into FormData or Array using JavaScript. Then you can send that variable to next page in URL

Check this:

```js
function getFieldArray()
{
 console.log('Example : 1 Get all fields in FormData Array');
 var formData = new FormData();
 var elements = document.getElementById("myForm1").elements;
 for (var i = 0, element; element = elements[i++];) {
  if (element.type === "text")
  {
   console.log('This is textbox id = ' + element.id + ', Value = ' + element.value);
   formData.append(element.id, element.value);
  }
 }
 
 //Example : 1  END
 console.log('\n-----------------------------\n\n');
 
 
 console.log('Example : 2 Get all fields in Array');
 var fieldsArr = [];
 var frmElements = document.getElementById("myForm1").elements;
 for (var i = 0, element; element = frmElements[i++];) {
  if (element.type === "text")
  {
   fieldsArr[i] = element.value;
  }
 }
 console.log('Fields Length : ' + fieldsArr.length);

 return false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm1">
  First name:<br>
  <input id="firstname" type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey">
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input id="lastname" type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse">
  <br><br>
  <button onclick="return getFieldArray()">Submit</button>
 </form>
```

Latter on you can send FormData to another page.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'new_page.html',
    data: formData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function (response) {
        //alert('done')
    },
    error: function (error) {
        //alert('fail');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The serializeArray() function will give you all the data that you have submitted in your form, just call that function on your form.